# Java / SAP HYBRIS : Timezone Date Issues in Java/hybris Backoffice

Tags: java, date, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using sap cx version 20.03

I added an attribute in my model of type date.

```
<attribute qualifier="date" type="java.util.Date" >
<persistence type="property" />
<modifiers optional="true" />
<description>order date</description>
</attribute>
```

So, I have entered `Tue Jun 08 19:00:00 WEST 2021` in the date field and after saving the model the value is getting saved as `Tue Jun 08 20:00:00 WEST 2021` in the database. The server is in Africa/Casablanca timezone. Please explain how this conversion is happening !

I need to save the date as the user chose it. `Tue Jun 08 19:00:00 WEST 2021`

Here is the configuration at the backoffice level.

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="date" editor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.defaulttime">             
   <editorArea:editor-parameter>
      <editorArea:name>timeFormat</editorArea:name>
      <editorArea:value>short</editorArea:value>
    </editorArea:editor-parameter>
</editorArea:attribute>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your timezone? If it's different from the server timezone, it will not match with Backoffice timezone, because Backoffice is usually based on your/browser timezone.

Comment: I'm saving Date. for my needs I have field date and a list of times zones in BO I format the date to have HH: mm. so, when the user chooses a date and a time zone, I want to save it in the DB with this time zone example the user chosen for example 16:00 and time zone GMT+2, the value I want to save is 16:00 in GMT + 2
I added a prepareInterceptor and I set the time zone chosen by the user, but he converted it he added 2 hours in the time.

Comment: I want to indicate that this date is in a time zone chosen by the user without converting it and without converting it by default to the time zone server which is Africa/Casablanca for my case

Comment: any solution for this?